# Redirect to home if user is null in NextJS 13 with auth context

Tags: authentication, next.js, jwt, react-context

i am implementing auth system with jwt in my next app. But i am having an issue when i work with protected page, here is my profile page (protected page):

```
'use client'
import { useContext, useEffect } from "react"
import { AuthContext } from "@/contexts/AuthContext"
import { useRouter } from 'next/navigation'

const Profile = () => {
    const router = useRouter()
    const { user, statusAuth } = useContext(AuthContext)

    useEffect(() => {
        if(statusAuth === 'unauthenticated' && !user) {
            router.push('/')
        } else {
            return
        }
    }, [router, statusAuth, user])

    if (statusAuth === 'loading') return <>loading.........</>

    return (
        <div>Profile user is here {user?.email}</div>
    )
}

export default Profile
```

And this is my auth context

```
const [user, setUser] = useState<IUser | null>(null)

const [statusAuth, setStatusAuth] = useState('unauthenticated')

const checkIsLoggedin = async () => {
    setStatusAuth('loading')
    try {
        const data = await AxiosGlobal.get('/auth/getMe')
        if (data.status === 200) {
            setUser(data.data.user)
            setStatusAuth('authenticated')
        } else {
            setUser(null)
            setStatusAuth('unauthenticated')
        }
    } catch (error) {
        setUser(null)
        setStatusAuth('unauthenticated')
    }
}
useEffect(() => {
    checkIsLoggedin()
}, [])

 return (
    <AuthContext.Provider
        value={{
            user,
            setUser,
            statusAuth,
            setStatusAuth,
        }}
    >
        {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
)
```

and this is my axios config

```
import axios from "axios";

//for handle multiple request

let isRefreshing: boolean = false
let failedQueue: any = []

const processQueue = (error: any, token = null) => {
    failedQueue.forEach((prom: any) => {
        if(error) {
            prom.reject(error)
        } else {
            prom.resolve(token)
        }
    })
    failedQueue = []
}

const AxiosGlobal = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:5000/api/v1',
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    withCredentials: true,
    timeout: 6000
})

AxiosGlobal.interceptors.request.use(async (config) => {

    //we dont need attach access token when we 
    if(config.url === '/auth/refresh-token' && config.method === 'post') {
        return config
    }
    const token = localStorage.getItem('accessToken') as string;

    if(token) {
        config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`
    }

    return config
}, (error) => {

    Promise.reject(error)
})

AxiosGlobal.interceptors.response.use((response) => response, async(error) => {
    const originalRequest = error?.config
    if(error?.response?.status === 401 && error?.response?.data?.error !== 'No token' && !originalRequest._retry) {
        if (isRefreshing) {
            return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                failedQueue.push({resolve, reject})
            }).then(token => {
                originalRequest.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`
                return AxiosGlobal(originalRequest)
            }).catch(err => {
                return Promise.reject(err)
            })
        }
        originalRequest._retry = true;
        isRefreshing = true
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            AxiosGlobal.post('/auth/refresh-token').then(({data}) => {
                localStorage.setItem('accessToken', JSON.stringify(data.token))
                AxiosGlobal.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = `Bearer ${data.token}`
                originalRequest.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + data.token;
                processQueue(null, data.token);
                resolve(AxiosGlobal(originalRequest));
            }).catch(err => {
                processQueue(err, null)
                reject(err)
            }).finally(() => {
                isRefreshing = false
            })
        })
    }
    if (error.code === 'ECONNABORTED' && error.message.includes('timeout')) {
        console.log('Request timed out');
        return Promise.reject(error);
    }
    
    return Promise.reject(error);
})

export default AxiosGlobal
```

when i logged in, and i access /profile directly by url, first it show Profile user is here and then redirect to /, which is not true. i dont know what wrong in my code. Does anyone has any idea? thank you

Comment: can you please create https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

i've found a solution for this, just need to change the initial state of statusAuth from 'unauthenticated' to 'loading'

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).